# Is there any case where a class with deleted ctor could be useful?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I wonder why the standard allows this kind of declaration.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : bar(0){}
    A(int foo) : bar(foo){}
private:
    int bar;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() = delete;
};
```

B can't be instantiated.

```
  B b1; //error: use of deleted function ‘B::B()’
  B b2(2); //error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B(int)’
```

still true with

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : bar(0){}
private:
    int bar;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() = delete;
};
```

which gives

```
B b1; //error: use of deleted function ‘B::B()’
```

note: this is different with not having a default ctor:

```
class G
{
protected:
    int assign;
};

class H : public G
{
public:
    H() = delete;
};
```

gives

```
G g1; //works
//H h1; -- error: use of deleted function ‘H::H()’
```

Is there any case where this can be useful?

Comment: If you have an RAII class that should acquire a resource on construction then not having a default constructor is a good thing.

Comment: Can you expand on where you think inheritance comes into this, and why you think an unrelated base class constructor is relevant?

Comment: That is not the `delete` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any case where a class with deleted ctor could be useful?

Classes can be used without creating instances. Most typical examples of such classes are type traits: All features of for example `std::is_same` and `std::numeric_limits` can be used without creating an instance. As such, their constructor could be deleted without losing any functionality.

That said, it is typically not necessary to delete the constructor of such classes, and in fact the implicit contsructors of standard type traits are not deleted. Deletion of constructors is typically used to remove only certain constructors, rather than all of them. To be clear: Just because something isn't typical, doesn't mean that it should be an error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are very many times when a class without a default constructor is useful.

In fact, most of my classes have no default constructor. They take some options or some initial state, instead.

Even when it isn't "useful" in that sense (like when you leave *no* other constructor available), there would be no need for the standard to go out of its way to prohibit it, because then implementations would have to go out of their way to implement the prohibition, for no gain at all. Like, if it means the class design makes no sense, then that's your fault and you can simply rewrite the class to more properly suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the question here is not whether classes with deleted default constructors are useful, but instead, whether classes *that cannot be constructed* are useful.

I think that the answer is "no", but the standard does not anticipate and ban all possible cases of useless declarations.

Comment: really "no" ? what about type traits?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 and why would you bother deleting the constructor of a traits class?

Comment: maybe I wouldnt but still a type trait that cannot be constructed can be useful. "whether classes that cannot be constructed are useful." yes, you do not need to contruct an instance of a trait to be useful. Maybe I am just too much picking on words though...

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I see what you're saying. I suppose that my answer makes more sense if you interpret it as "the *feature* of being able to define classes that cannot be constructed is not useful".

Comment: the question could also be read as "is it useful to prevent a class from being instantiated", then I could agree on a "no", because one can make a trait non-instantiable but I also fail to see the benefit

Comment: yeah same thoughts here, just slower in writing the comment ;)

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Type traits should absolutely be default constructible. They should be usable for tag dispatch.